# How To Display Data Selected Datasets' Feature With R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to display  selected feature of selected data in R Shiny.
To select data I use select input (with reactivity) , and to choose features of selected dataset use checkboxGroupInput.

I know there is some mistake in my code. Here is my code how can I act it?

```
    Server- Code
 Data_to_display <<- reactive({
    switch(input$Data,
           "dt_1" = Data1,
           "dt_2" = Data2)
  })

 output$DisplayData <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(Data_to_display(), filter="top")
    })

UI.Code
------

sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel( 
      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Gösterilecek özellikler:",
                         names(Data), selected = names(Data)),
      selectInput("Data", "Choose data:", choices =  c("dt_1","dt_2"), selected = "dt_1")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("DisplayData") 
    )
```

Comment: Could you  please show your complet code

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling a reactive input (`Data`) in the `ui`. [To build dynamic UI that reacts to user input](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html), you can create the UI element on the `server` and then output the element in the `ui`.

However, I'm not sure of your exact goal. If you'd like to hide/show columns in the datatable there is a [DT extension (colvis) for exactly that purpose](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).

I've added two examples below -- one with dynamically rendered checkboxes and another with the DT extension for hiding/showing columns.

---

1) Dynamically created checkboxes:

```
    Data1 <- iris
    Data2 <- mtcars

    ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout( 
            sidebarPanel( 
                selectInput("Data", "Choose data:", 
                            choices =  c("dt_1","dt_2"), selected = "dt_1"),
                ## render dynamic checkboxes
                uiOutput("show_vars")
                ),

            mainPanel(
                DT::dataTableOutput("DisplayData")
            )
        )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

        Data_to_display <<- reactive({
            switch(input$Data,
                   "dt_1" = Data1,
                   "dt_2" = Data2)
        })

        ### create dynamic checkboxes
        output$show_vars <- renderUI({
            checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Gösterilecek özellikler:",
                               choices = names(Data_to_display()), 
                               selected = names(Data_to_display()))
        })

        output$DisplayData <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(Data_to_display(), filter="top")
        })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

2) DT extension colvis:

```
Data1 <- iris
Data2 <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout( 
        sidebarPanel( 
            selectInput("Data", "Choose data:", 
                        choices =  c("dt_1","dt_2"), selected = "dt_1")),
        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("DisplayData")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    Data_to_display <<- reactive({
        switch(input$Data,
               "dt_1" = Data1,
               "dt_2" = Data2)
    })

    ### hide/show columns with built-in DT extension
    output$DisplayData <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(Data_to_display(), filter = "top",
                      extensions = 'Buttons',
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = I('colvis')))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tryed both of solutions. They worked with the sample datasets. But when I tryed to apply it to my dataset, it didn't work (although I try to change dataset from select input, it didnt change) . Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @ismailduru Can you share your datasets and/or the edits you made to the code?